# Find the limit of $\frac{e^{2z}-e^{-z}}{z}$ when $z \to 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the limit of $\frac{e^{2z}-e^{-z}}{z}$ when $z \to 0$.

$$\frac{e^{2z}-e^{-z}}{z} = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(2^{k+1}-(-1)^{k+1}) z^k}{(k+1)!}$$ From this equality, is anyone could help me how to proceed to find the limit? Otherwise, is there exist a clever way to do it?

Comment: "Clever"? Probably not, but easy: $e^{2z}=1+2z+o(z)$, $e^{-z}=1-z+o(z)$, hence $e^{2z}-e^{-z}=3z+o(z)$ and the limit is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(e^{2z}-e^{-z})}{z}
$$
Applying L'Hopital:
$$
\lim_{z\to 0} (2e^{2z}+e^{-z}) = 3
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is a variation rate, hence the limit is the derivative of $\mathrm e^{2z}-\mathrm e^{-z}$ at $z=0$:
$$2\mkern1.5mu\mathrm e^{2z}+\mathrm e^{-z}\biggr\rvert_{z=0}=3.$$